# SQL Duplicate Telephone Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery

I have two tables with Telephone numbers and I want to run a query to check if there are any duplicate telephone numbers in both tables. The tables are called class1 and class2 I have come up with the following query:

```
Select * 
from Class1 
where Telephone in (select 
               Telephone 
               from Class2
               group by Telephone
               having count(*) > 1)
```

It does not work can anybody please help me?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: If you drop the GROUP BY and HAVING clause you'll get the results you want I believe.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? The same number in both tables or duplicates within every table?

Comment: You want to check in same tables or check class1 column with class2 coulmn?

Comment: I dont understnad I am knew to SQL what would the query look like?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two things:

```
Select * from Class1 where Telephone in (select Telephone from Class2);
```

gives you all numbers that are present in both tables.

```
Select Telephone from Class1 group by Telephone having count(*) > 1;
```

gives you all duplicate numbers in Class1.

You can combine these:

```
Select 'Class1' as whattable, Telephone from Class1 group by Telephone having count(*) > 1
union all
Select 'Class2' as whattable, Telephone from Class2 group by Telephone having count(*) > 1
union all
Select 'both' as whattable, Telephone from Class1 where Telephone in (select Telephone from Class2);
```

Comment: `select *` in your 2nd code block fails if there's another column in Class1 then Telephone, should be `Select Telephone`

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected my answer.